# How to create Pie charts inside buttons in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For my internship I'm currently developing a monitoring tool and my boss would like me to display multiple clickable pie charts on the home screen.

I'm trying to find a rather simple solution as I'm not exactly proficient in MVC.

Is it possible to include them inside buttons, do I need to create multiple partial views per pie chart or is there any other better ways to proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: try this https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/integration/asp-net-mvc-charts/types/asp-net-mvc-pie-charts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MS Chart Controls](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61/view/SamplePack#content) to create any type of charts. It will return you a chart in form of an image.

You can easily write a click event for image as shown below:

```
<img id="chartCustmor" alt="Chart" onclick="CallJavaScriptFuncitonHere()" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this, it seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please upvote and accept the answer. It helps others.